# DBpedia getting page category using sparql

Tags: r, sparql, dbpedia

I am using DBpedia to getting page category using SPARQL in R. However, there are having some problems on it. Source code I am using:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>  
SELECT ?categoryUri ?categoryName WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/xxx> dcterms:subject ?categoryUri.
         ## xxx are random words (e.g. Agree, Film, Work, Plan...)
    ?categoryUri rdfs:label ?categoryName.
    FILTER (lang(?categoryName) = "en")
}
```

The problems are:

1. Category cannot be retrieved if the words need to be redirected (e.g. Agree -> Agreement)
2. Disambiguation pages cannot be used from the above source code, because there are so many sub-pages within the category of word (e.g. Work)

So, how can I resolve the above problems? I am really appreciate if anyone can offer your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPARQL does only do what you write, so there is no magic behind. If some resource `:s` is possibly connected to others by a property `:p`, add a triple pattern `:s :p ?o .` - sometimes you might even consider to use a property path in case of the resolution of the transitive closure of `:p`, i.e. `:s :p* ?o .`.

With redirects resolved:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT * WHERE
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agree> (dbo:wikiPageRedirects)* ?page
    OPTIONAL
      { ?page dcterms:subject ?categoryUri}
  }
```

Note the `OPTIONAL` clause, which is necessary here because not all resources in DBpedia belong to a category.

Including disambiguation pages:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT * WHERE
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agree> (dbo:wikiPageRedirects)*/(dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates)* ?page
    OPTIONAL
      { ?page dcterms:subject ?categoryUri}
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer :) However, I am still having one more question on the "Disambiguates" page. For example, when I query "Work" in the dbpedia (http://dbpedia.org/page/Work), it does not returns "Microsoft Works". But When I run your query, I see that included in the result. Is "Microsoft Works" a subpage of "Work"?

Comment: I don't know how the data is retrieved for the web pages. Maybe there is a limit or it's a bug. But if you have a look at http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microsoft_Works, there is the inverse direction to http://dbpedia.org/resource/Work listed by "is dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates of"