# How to retrieve DBPedia 'class' attribute for a given word using Sparql?

Tags: java, class, sparql, ontology, dbpedia

So I have a word like, for example, 'Horse', and I want to retrieve its class. That would be 'Mammal', as shown here: http://dbpedia.org/page/Horse .

I tried something, but it's not returning anything.

```
String queryString =  "PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"
                    + "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                    + "select ?class where {dbr:Horse dbo:?class}";
```

Any advices ?

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL queries make use of so-called triple patterns, your query returns only a tuple and the second part even in strange syntax. Moreover, instances are asserted to classes by `rdf:type` property. `dbo:class` on the other hand is more a property for the biological term class. Obviously, your query is ill-formed and the `dbo:class` part overlap with the `?class` variable. I'm wondering why you didn't see that - it's too obvious...

```sql
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?class WHERE {
  dbr:Horse dbo:class ?class
}
```

Comment: Maybe because I'm new to SPARQL... then how do I get the type of the word ?

Comment: There is no term "word" in RDF. What do you mean? The classes a resource (which is identified by a URI/IRI) belongs to? IF yes, then just use the `rdf:type` relation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. It's just a missunderstanding of mine, since I'm new to this. What I want is the following: taking the category of the resource having its name.

Comment: I tried what was written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429269/dbpedia-getting-page-category-using-sparql , but I get like A LOT OF categories. Don't know if that's the right approach to do this.

Comment: Now you want to get the categories...that's not the same as types, but anyways, it's correct to use `dct:subject` as predicate then. Maybe it's not clear to you, but everything on http://dbpedia.org/page/Horse shows the predicates with its values - and indeed there can be multiple values for the same property in RDF. And the categories in DBpedia are simply the ones from the corresponding Wikipedia page.

Comment: I tried this, and it works in some cases: 

SELECT ?categories
WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/They> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?categories}

but seems like I don't get any category of the "They" keyword, for example, from wikipedia, which should be English grammar, Modern English personal pronouns, Middle English personal pronouns. 

P.S.: I suppose the resources that have "Disambiguation pages" as category should not return anything.

Comment: Simple answer: There is no such data about categories of "They" in DBpedia. I mean, you can always check this at the corresponding page: http://dbpedia.org/page/They . The reason might be that the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They) doesn't have an infobox, thus, a different extraction strategy is used.

Comment: I uderstood. So my last query is the one I was searching for. Thank you very much for your time !